# logging info/debug messages in google cloud apache beam python sdk

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wanted to print info or debug or exception messages on screen while running the dataflow program. I am able to do this when running the pipeline with the runner as "DirectRunner". But the same program does not print anything on the dataflow console while running with the runner "DataflowRunner". Here is the  code, its very basic.

```
 import apache_beam as beam
 from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
 from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
 from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
 from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
 import logging

 class ProcessData(beam.DoFn):

   def process(self, element, var):
     logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
     logging.info("Print the element %s",element)
     logging.info("Print the var %s",var)

 logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
 #Initialize the pipeline
 pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
 pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
 p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

 p | 'Read the data file' >> beam.io.textio.ReadFromText('gs://rohan_staging/data/test.txt') | 'Process Data' >> beam.ParDo(ProcessData(),1)
 p.run()
```

I was able to see the messages earlier on the console, but suddenly i have stopped seeing them. I don't know what i did wrong or what was i doing different before. Please suggest how to i see info messages on the cloud dataflow console.

Answer (score 3):

I see no issue in the snippet that you shared, in fact it is compliant with all the steps provided in the documentation to [Log Pipeline Messages in Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/logging). Therefore, I have run a sample pipeline with your code and was able to verify that everything is being logged successfully (see logs `Print the element...` in screenshots 2 and 3):

- *Job logs:*
  [image]
- *Logs at the **Process Data** step:*
  [image]
- *Logs in Stackdriver Logging:*
  [image]

---

As explained in the logging documentation I linked earlier, the *Step Logs* and *Job Logs* tab only show the most recent and relevant logs for the step or job, respectively, so you should go to the Stackdriver logs of your pipeline in order to have a complete view of your logs (which you can later filter based on your preferences).

Given that you said that you were able to see the logs earlier but not anymore, there are several things that can be happening:

1. You were previously inspecting the Step logs (where the logs you added are shown), and now you are looking at the Job logs (which do not display them).
2. The logs have disappeared from the *Step logs* tab, which only show recent logs.
3. Your logs have expired from Stackdriver (as per the [retention limits](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods)).

Comment: Thanks for checking and sending all the details. I ran the code with the following command: python test_print.py --runner 'DataflowRunner' --project 'syw-analytics-repo-dev' --staging_location 'gs://rohan_staging/staging' --temp_location 'gs://rohan_staging/temp' --job_name testprint                                                                                             But i still don't see the step logs. I am not able to attach the screenshot, but the step log has nothing and neither does the stackdriver. Is it because i am using version 2.4.0? I could upgrade to latest version and try.

Comment: I also tried using the parameter --output 'gs://rohan_staging/data/logs.txt'  to save the logging statements in this file, but this file was not even created.

Comment: Regarding the `--output` flag, I think you are confused by the fact that the [quickstart guides](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/) include it, but it does not work by default, it works because there is [a transform in the code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py#L109) that writes the output to text files.

Comment: On the other hand, I find it really strange that the exact same code prints logs in my case but not in yours. Here you can find more information about [logging in the *Dataflow Runner*](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#logging), but I guess you have not overriden the default configurations, have you? Additionally, could you try running the code using *DirectRunner* like `python pipe.py --runner DirectRunner`? Do logs appear using it? In my case, they do appear, with an INFO level.

Comment: Yes,the logs show up if i run using --runner DirectRunner. I think the logs do not appear when i run using dataflow, because maybe the stackdriver logging is disabled at the project level for dataflow. Will check with the Project owner about this.

Comment: Hi @RohanAhire, were you able to solve this issue? Even for us, the logs are not coming in DataflowRunner whereas in DirectRunner it's coming. Stackdriver logs are already enabled for dataflow. Any other issue that you found? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

For me the step logs don't appear in the Dataflow console. I need to go into Stackdriver and use an advanced filter:

```
resource.type="dataflow_step"
resource.labels.job_name="my job name"
resource.labels.step_id:"my step name"
```

This way I can see the log messages from my job step which were logged using the python logger.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this. I'm *still* seeing this issue - but I saw change across time. That is, earlier in the day, I got the logs on the stackdriver pop-up, and later in the day, it stopped working.

It seems that, in general, the python beam runner is not maintained very well.

Comment: This is not an answer and would be more helpful as a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I was able to follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) to set up cloud logging in python. Essentially, you need to connect the python root logger to the cloud logging library for the logs to show up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).